# Database: store hashtag with or without hash

Tags: database, postgresql, hashtag

I am writing a mobile app where users can tag an item with hashtags like Twitter does. To the user, he sees the hashtags as #thisisahashtag.

However I am wondering if I should store the hashtag in the database along with the hash? Or strip it out and just store "thisisahashtag"? Or does it not make any difference? I am on Postgresql DB by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider:

- How will other systems use this data? Will they need to know the context of the '#' character? Or would they just be interested in the content value?
- How will searching/indexing be affected?
- How will data storage/sizing be affected?

It seems the hashtag character is markup as it is used by the UI to either take a specific action when selected or identify the content as a "hashtag" to the user, and not part of the data proper.